# Creating a floating "div" within a responsive site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I'm a computer science student, in order to expand my knowledge I decided to build a responsive shopping site. I built the site using bootstrap. And the whole site is ready. Now I want to show the user the amount of his purchase. When he clicks on the shopping cart icon - pops div - fixed on the site. And when the user clicks on the shopping cart again - the div is deleted. To add and delete the shopping cart - use the ontoggle event.

My question is how can I add a div that will contain text for the products the user wants to buy - by "hovering" or staying "fixed" on the screen?

I tried to use fixed, or relative and absolute positioning. But in all times they took part of the site - and not "float" on it
I uploaded the full code to github.

Thanks for the help

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0suIj.png]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want your popup to float on the site, you want to use `position: fixed`.
Then you can play with `z-index` if you have many elements to put one above the other.
Note that it would also work with `position: absolute`. Both of those positioning take the item on another level of the layout, keeping the rest unchanged.

jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/p86nfrxc/1